# Ignoring localisation conversion within a PHP function

Tags: php, locale

I've built a multi-language site and I have both locales installed on the server. That's all good. However I have a PHP function that calculates the ratio of an image and returns it throughout my site. Only issue is it's returning the ratio with a comma (because of the localisation).

Any way to turn off the conversion for the following function?

```
function getRatio($width,$height) {
    $ratio = round($height/$width*100,2);
    $format = $height>$width;
    if ($format) {
        echo "data-format='portrait'";
    } else {
        echo "data-format='landscape'";
    }
    echo "style='padding-bottom:$ratio%;'";
}
```

Then in my templates:

```
<?php echo getRatio($image->width,$image->height); ?>
```

Comment: You could also just [number format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) the whole thing? It's easier and more maintainable in my experience.

Comment: @Loek This looks good. Can you explain how? So instead of round use number_format?

Comment: For example. Or use `round()` and then put it through `number_format`. The examples in the docs are pretty clear I guess. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @Loek Okay great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easier to just use [`number_format()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). This is easier to maintain and is consistent for every locale.

Note that number_format also rounds, so you can remove the `round()` from your code.

```
// 2 decimals, comma for thousands and point for decimals
$ratio = number_format($height / $width * 100, 2, ".", ",");

// 2 decimals, point for thousands and comma for decimals
$ratio = number_format($height / $width * 100, 2, ",", ".");

// 10 decimals, no thousands and point for decimals
$ratio = number_format($height / $width * 100, 10, ".");

// etc etc etc
```

Comment: I'll never use `round()` again ;)

Comment: Hahaha. It has its uses but `number_format` is nice indeed ;)